# Unable to build sample project for Support v4

Tags: android, sdk

Hi I am trying to build the sample package v4 in the Androidsdk\extras\android\support\v4\samples/. I also added the support v4 package to the build list. 
However when I do this Eclipse reports that the project is giving loads of compile errors eg:

1. setContentView(R.layout.accessibility_delegate); reports an error saying R cannot be resolved to a variable
2. its unable to find: R.layout.accessibility_manager); when its in the layout folder.

Some help on this would be really well received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> setContentView(R.layout.accessibility_delegate); reports an error
>   saying R cannot be resolved to a variable

Either your resource directory have not compiled properly, or you need to import `R`. You can search [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=R%20can%20not%20be%20resolved) for possible reasons and solutions.

> its unable to find: R.layout.accessibility_manager); when its in the
>   layout folder.

Possibly above solution, would also fix this.

If you are getting problem, in resolving .xml error while compiling `v4 samples`, then try to set Android target of your project to some higher API level  say API 13 (as some of the resources e.g theme were introduced in later versions). And do not worry as these samples still would run on older platforms, as `minSdkVersion` has been set so.

Hope it helps or you can elaborate your problem.

Comment: the project that androidbloke is talking about is supposed to be a sample project showing the APIs for v4.  it would appear from the comment that it does want Android API level 11 or higher, but what i want to know is why they set such a theme dependency in a sample that is supposed to be working with API level 4 ?!?

Comment: @john, IMO the support package comes only in picture when you want to work on API 11 or higher, but also want your application to work on phones supporting < API 11. So to me, it seems right that v4 requires target with API level 11 or higher.